# User Authentication Failed after Updating Password in Magento and Paypal Payment Advanced

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

Paypal Payment Advanced is working until I updated the password in Paypal and now it gives me error of "User Authentication Failed". I confirm my credentials and redo all the steps in setting up the PayPal in manager.paypal.com and also on Magento. It occurs after clicking the "Place Order" button. Can someone give me pointers on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Have you verified that there are no lower store-scope settings which are affecting things? Turned on PayPal debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually noticed a bug in Magento that can cause this issue if your password contains special characters. Try changing your password and remove any special characters from it.